# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row[OBJECT_COLUMN_NAME] = key') | React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, runtime-error, react-native

Currently, I am building a MobileApp with React-Native and everything works fine until today :/

Unfortunately today the app throws an error (see below) after a successful build!
`[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row[OBJECT_COLUMN_NAME] = key')]`
**BUT** this error only appears in the **normal mode** -> if I switch to the **debug mode** everything is working without any further problems.

[image: Debug Mode]

So after that, I started searching the trigger of this error and I found it (See below)
`Your_App/node_modules/react-native/Libaries/polyfills/console.js (Line 449)`

[image: Error Class]

But as you can see that isn't from me it's from React-Native and I am not able to resolve this problem 
After a long research on the internet, I couldn't figure out anything because nobody has got this error yet :/

But I think it has something to do with the newest react-native **firebase version 6.0.0** (https://invertase.io/blog/react-native-firebase-v6)
Because it fails near there (See below)

[image]

Note: After recreating the app (not hard with git) the error appears again after a while :/

Note: A empty App still works on my engine

**What do I use:**

- react-native 0.61.5
- java 13
- ([All used libraries](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/637935138671558656/690085538619064320/ReadMe))

I would appreciate help ^^

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I filled my code completely with console.logs... I found out that **React Native does not work with console.table in non debug mode.**
This is easily fixed by using console.table only when the app is in debug mode. Just check if the debug mode is enabled ^^

```
 const isDebuggingEnabled = (typeof atob !== 'undefined');
```

That's it

Comment: LOL Thank the LORD you posted this. I would have lost my mind.